# Tight binding of monoatomic chain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, tight-binding

For the the 1D atomic chain tight binding calculation, if we choose 1 atom per unit cell, the band dispersion is simply: $\epsilon-2t\cos{(ka)}$.
[image]

However, if we redefine our unit cell as 2 atoms, 3 atoms...n atoms. Why don't we end up with a $n\times n$ hamiltonian and end up with n different bands? It seems now the number of bands depends on the choice of the unit cell. Where is the logic loophole here?
Thanks!

Comment: The dispersion relation you have written down is only for one band alone. If you actually had that primitive unit cell, you ought to have infinite number of bands, each having similar dispersion relations for different t values. When you choose non-primitive unit cells, each band gets folded back onto itself and thus one band appears as two, three, etc. It is always proved in textbooks, even bad ones, that the total number states will be correctly captured regardless of how you choose things. You should just do the problems in the textbooks for these results.

Comment: No, but even if you construct an n x n matrix, the t values are the same, because the atoms are same and we only consider the nearest-neighbor hopping.

Answer (score 2):

If you increase the size of your unit cell, you *decrease* the size of the unit cell in reciprocal space.  In one dimension, the length of the unit cell in reciprocal space is $2\pi/a$, where $a$ is the length of the unit cell in direct space.

Now, the dispersion relation (ignoring the physically irrelevant offset $\epsilon$) is given by
$$
 - 2t\cos(ka)\,,
$$
where $a$ is the length of a *primitive* unit cell (a unit cell that contains only one lattice point). Crucially, $k$ takes values between $-\pi/a$ and $\pi/a$, i.e., inside the first Brillouin zone in reciprocal ($k$) space, because the dispersion relation (and in fact, the corresponding normal modes/eigenstates) is periodic with period $2\pi/a$.  The result is a diagram like that below (solid black and dashed curves) in the figure below.

[image]

However, let's suppose we decide to enlarge the unit cell in direct space as OP has shown.  Then, the length of the unit cell is $a'=3a$: the length has tripled. The length of the corresponding unit cell in *reciprocal* space is therefore cut by a factor of 3; its length is $2\pi/a' = 2\pi/3a$. Hence, when we go to plot the dispersion relation, we have to plot it between $-2\pi/3$ and $2\pi /3a$. In order not to *lose* any of the dispersion relation, though, we have to *shift* the "branches" of the dispersion relation that our outside of the new first Brillouin zone *in*to the new first Brillouin zone.

The result is a plot of the dispersion relation in what's called *reduced zone scheme*, shown as the solid curve in the figure.  We've traded a smaller Brillouin zone for multiple bands of the dispersion relation, but it still represents the same physics. For each state, we now have $k$-index *and* a band index, and the two together form unique value of $k$ in the *original* Brillouin zone.

So, the upshot is that you absolutely *can* do this, but it's not actually a convenient representation of the physics. *However*, when the symmetry of the system is reduced somehow, say, by replacing every third atom by a different one (or, by changing the energy $\epsilon$ on every third site), we *have* to go to this reduced zone scheme, because the primitive unit cell in the new lattice would be exactly the one we've shown. The result would be that gaps would open up a the new Brillouin zone boundary, and there really would be three different (separated) bands.

Thus, going to reduced zone scheme is an important first step in the process of computing the new dispersion relation when the symmetry of the system is reduced.  For a clear application of this, see the nearly-free electron model in any solid state physics text.

Comment: Hi March, thank you for your detailed explanation and plotting, it is very illustrative and helpful! It solves most of my confusion but I still have some follow-up questions:

Comment: 1. From my understanding, the first Brillouin zone reflects the symmetry of the underlying lattice of the crystal. So it should relates to the "primitive unit cell", not "unit cell". As long as the symmetry properties of the lattice does not change, the size of the Brillouin zone should not change--even if you redefine unit cell. Only when there is physical change with your system, i.e. the Peierls distortion in CDW, or the 3rd atom change as you mentioned, the Brillouin zone changes because the "true" lattice constant is doubled or tripled. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: 2. Let's say if we make a three atom unit cell. How would the matrix representation of the Hamiltonian looks like (if we only assume nearest neighbor hopping)? I would say it is a 3x3 matrix with all matrix elements be the same and equal to -1/3t*cos(ka). Is this correct?
(Sorry for asking so many questions, and I really appreciate your help on a Friday afternoon :) )